# Snowflake Grant Select on single schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

db: my_db

schemas: my_schema_1, my_schema_2

tables:

- my_schema_1: table_a, table_b
- my_schema_2: table_c, table_d

I would like to grant select to all tables in my_schema_2.

```
use role securityadmin;
grant usage 
  on database my_db 
  to role dw_ro_role;

grant usage on schema my_db.my_schema_2
  to role dw_ro_role;

grant select
  on all tables in schema my_db.my_schema_2
  to role dw_ro_role;
```

However, this grants access to ALL schemas in the database. (I think through granting usage)  In fact, if I:

```
grant usage on my_db...
revoke select on all tables in my_schema_2
```

I can still query everything.

If I revoke usage on database my_db, I cannot query anything.

The owner of my_db is sysadmin.  The owner of the schemas is etl_tool_role.

How can I allow access to select from tables in a only chosen schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grants look just fine, so I'm wondering how you are accessing/testing this.
Or maybe the `role dw_ro_role` has more grants in effect than you've shown above.

If you log onto the DB with a user that has just the `role dw_ro_role` and the same as the default role, you should only get access to `schema my_db.my_schema_2`.

Comment: I agree with the answer above.  These look good and either you are testing with a different role or that role has more grants in affect already.  The only additional comment is you might want to consider adding a grant to future tables in the schema, as well, so you don't need to keep running your grants when new tables are created.

Comment: Like Mike said check your `PUBLIC` role or any other role that already has grants.